# Delete from array when li is outside selection area

Tags: jquery, select, mouseevent, area

I coding a selection area with mouse events of jQuery but i have a issue, i try to delete info from array, where i save the info of the selectables li's, when mouse leave it and it's out of the selection area. Thanks for all.

[EX: This is the work that i do it](http://jsbin.com/hihox)

Comment: I just checked your code and demo, observged that the array and selected LI's are not getting reverted after leaving the mouse. So you want help to make that happen, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize the files array and revert the CSS rules added for LI's upon 'mouseup' event, so new code block for 'mouseup' event handler looks like:

`.mouseup(function(e){
  page.off('mousemove');
  li.off('mouseover');
  selection.hide();
  // Added code lines
  files = [];
  li.css({'background':'transaparent'});
});`

Updated your demo page code, so now you can check the selection behavior in a new [demo page](http://jsbin.com/baxogumo/1).

**Update 1:**

Refer the below code block which hides the elements out of selection area upon 'mouseup' event.

`.mouseup(function(e){
  page.off('mousemove');
  li.off('mouseover');
  selection.hide();
  li.each(function(){
    if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('class'), files) == -1) {
      $(this).css({'display':'none'});
      //$(this).remove(); // This statement removes the element from DOM
    }
  });
});`

Demo Link: http://jsbin.com/baxogumo/2

**Update 2:**

Made required changes, so now this should work in the way how you wanted, have a look the below specified demo link.

Now we are handling the list items selection upon 'mouseup' event by considering the performance and to make it working properly.

Demo Link: http://jsbin.com/hotiwiro/2

Comment: I dont want clear the Array on mouseup, i want delete single item when it isnt in selection area. Thanks and regards!

Comment: you want to delete a single item or all the items out of selected area?

Comment: Updated my answer with a new code block to hide/remove the items out of selected area, included demo link also.

Comment: i want to delete the items that arent into select area but are in the array, for example, i strat to drag the cursor and i add multiple items to array, but without stop holding left cursor i change the select area getting out from some item.

Comment: did you checked my recent demo link? do you want reverse operation of that??

Comment: i think u dont understand me, take the selection area of your so, when you hovered an icon and getting out it, this icon is selected and unselected. u know??

Comment: oh ok, so unselected items are still in that array as per the current logic.

Comment: seems like you want to remove the items from array once they gets selected and unselected,right?

Comment: i think so, its like select area of any operative system, if the item is into select area, this is selected, else the item is unselected, changing its status when i change the select area dimensions.

Comment: Lukas, check my updated answer which has demo link(http://jsbin.com/hotiwiro/2) as well.